# fetch data is slow with key constructed from 3 columns

Tags: sql, entity-framework-6

I have this table:

```
    public class DataTable
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public long SeqNum { get; set; }

        [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        public int SourceId { get; set; }

        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        public int Epoc { get; set; }

        [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
        public int InternalSourceId { get; set; }

        public byte[] AllElementsData { get; set; }
    }
```

the table has millions of record

when i try to fetch a single value it works really fast but when i try to fetch a range of values its very very slow

here is my query:

```
            DataTable[] eeee = dbTables.DataTable.Where(c => (c.SourceId == 5 && c.Epoc == 5 && c.InternalSourceId  > 0) &&
                                                              (c.SourceId == 5 && c.Epoc == 5 && c.InternalSourceId < 5)).ToArray();
```

what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: no, will it improve the queries ? how do i do it ?

Comment: Give it a quick try - use SQL management studio (I'm assuming SQL Server here) and run `CREATE INDEX DataSrcAndEpoxIdx ON DataTable (SourceId, Epoc, InternalSourceId)` first. A single index might just work here.

Comment: this command will create an index on the current snapshot of the DB or it will continue to index from now on every new record  ?

Comment: Once an index is created, it is maintained through all table insertions/updates/deletions.

Comment: great - trying it now, thanks !!!